# Htaccess rewrite to certain page/language

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

Im trying to make a redirect listen to a certain domain.
I have 3 domains;
- www.tocdesal.com

- www.tocdesal.es
- www.tocdesal.nl

Now i want achieve this..

www.tocdesal.com > www.tocdesal.com/en_GB/

www.tocdesal.nl > www.tocdesal.com/nl_NL/

www.tocdesal.es > www.tocdesal.com/es_ES/

Here is some code i use to manage multilanguage and ban people form certain folders.
I hope somebody can help me with this feature.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Turn on URL rewriting
    RewriteEngine On

    # NON-WWW > WWW
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.tocdesal\.nl [NC]
    #RewriteRule (.*) http://www.tocdesal.nl/nl_NL/home/$1 [R=301,L]

    # CUSTOM REWRITES
    #Redirect 301 /[oldlink] [new-full-link]

    # We dont want snooping people
    Options -Indexes

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^framework.*

    # If your website begins from a folder e.g localhost/my_project then 
    # you have to change it to: RewriteBase /my_project/
    # If your site begins from the root e.g. example.local/ then
    # let it as it is
    #RewriteBase /tvmoordrecht

    # Protect application and system files from being viewed when the index.php is missing
    RewriteCond $1 ^(framework/modules|framework/coremodules|framework/cicore|application|assets|custommodules)

    # Rewrite to index.php/access_denied/URL
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/access_denied/$1 [PT,L]

    # Allow these directories and files to be displayed directly:
    RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|css|js|images|img|fonts|upload|framework/assets/|themes|framework/apps/elfinder|dev-cmslemonupdater|cmslemonupdater)

    # No rewriting
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [PT,L]

    # Rewrite to index.php/URL
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert these 3 rules right after `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?tocdesal\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^en_GB/ http://www.tocdesal.com/en_GB%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?tocdesal\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.tocdesal.com/nl_NL%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?tocdesal\.es$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.tocdesal.com/es_ES%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Sadly it didn't work. Still i got the endless redirect loop. I think maby its a problem in the other lines that is causing the problem. I dont have that maby talent in .htaccess

Comment: For which URL do you get looping?

Comment: The .es works now! Great! Is there also a way to make the non-www for all the domains seperatly go to www.tocdesal.* if that can be done im very very happy

Comment: Thank you @anubhava the solution works only when i put the .com rewrite in the .com flips and trips and loops again. I also put the rule as last in the order of the 3 rewrites but it didn't help. Its not very important that it works with the .com domain, that one is standard the English version.

Comment: I have made a correction in the first rule to prevent looping.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i have now. non-www redirects to www for the standard domain (.com) the rest redirects to the language on what the domain is set to.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Turn on URL rewriting
    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirects to the page with that language selected

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?tocdesal\.nl$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://www.tocdesal.com/nl_NL%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?tocdesal\.es$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://www.tocdesal.com/es_ES%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

    # CUSTOM REWRITES
    #Redirect 301 /[oldlink] [new-full-link]

    # We dont want snooping people
    Options -Indexes

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^framework.*

    # If your website begins from a folder e.g localhost/my_project then
    # you have to change it to: RewriteBase /my_project/
    # If your site begins from the root e.g. example.local/ then
    # let it as it is
    #RewriteBase /tvmoordrecht

    # Protect application and system files from being viewed when the index.php is mi
    RewriteCond $1 ^(framework/modules|framework/coremodules|framework/cicore|applica

    # Rewrite to index.php/access_denied/URL
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/access_denied/$1 [PT,L]

    # Allow these directories and files to be displayed directly:
    RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|css|js|images|img|fonts|uplo

    # No rewriting
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [PT,L]

    # Rewrite to index.php/URL
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```